# I got usernames to display on my site, but when I log in the username disappears

Tags: php, html

I am not a professional at this, so that being said everything is fairly new to me. I've been researching and trying to figure out my error, but no luck :(. Am I using `session_start()` wrong? Here is my code:

**profile.php** This is the page I want it to echo in.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("connect.php");
    include("functions.php");


   if(logged_in())
      {
?>



<?php 

}
else
{
    header("location:login.php");
    exit();
}?>

    <div id='userid'> <?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?></div>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("connect.php");
    include("functions.php");

if(logged_in())
{
    header("location:quotin.php");
    exit();
}

$error = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $_SESSION['email'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $_SESSION['firstName'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
    $_SESSION['lastName'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $_SESSION['userid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userid']);
    $_SESSION['image'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['image']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $checkBox = isset($_POST['keep']);

    if(email_exists($email,$con))
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        $retrievepassword = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if(!password_verify($password, $retrievepassword['password']))
        {
            $error = "Password is incorrect";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

            if($checkBox == "on")
            {
                setcookie("email",$email, time()+3600);
            }

            header("location: quotin.php");
        }


    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Email Does not exists";
    }


}?>

<body>

    <div id="error" style=" <?php  if($error !=""){ ?>  display:block; <?php } ?> "><?php echo $error; ?></div>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="menu">
            <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
        </div>

        <div id="formDiv">

            <form method="POST" action="login.php">

            <label>Email:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" class="inputFields"  name="email" required/><br/><br/>


            <label>Password:</label><br/>
            <input type="password" class="inputFields"  name="password" required/><br/><br/>

            <input type="checkbox" name="keep" />
            <label>Keep me logged in</label><br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="theButtons" value="login" />



            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("connect.php");
    include("functions.php");

if(logged_in())
{
    header("location:profile.php");
    exit();
}

$error = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   $_SESSION['email'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $_SESSION['firstName'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
    $_SESSION['lastName'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $_SESSION['userid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userid']);
    $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
    $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userid']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordConfirm = $_POST['passwordConfirm'];

    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

    $conditions = isset($_POST['conditions']);

    $date = date("F, d Y");


    if(strlen($firstName) < 3)
    {
        $error = "First name is too short";
    }

    else if(strlen($lastName) < 3)
    {
        $error = "Last name is too short";
    }
    else if(strlen($userid) > 8)
    {
        $error = "You need a longer username";
    }
    else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $error = "Please enter valid email address";
    }
    else if(email_exists($email, $con))
    {
        $error = "Someone is already registered with this email";
    }
    else if(strlen($password) < 8)
    {
        $error = "Password must be greater than 8 characters";
    }
    else if($password !== $passwordConfirm)
    {
        $error = "Password does not match";
    }
    else if($image == "")
    {
        $error = "Please upload your image";
    }
    else if($imageSize > 1048576)
    {
        $error = "Image size must be less than 1 mb";
    }           
    else if(!$conditions)
    {
        $error = "You must be agree with the terms and conditions";
    }
    else
    {   
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $imageExt = explode(".", $image);
            $imageExtension = $imageExt[1];

            if($imageExtension == "PNG" || $imageExtension == "png" || $imageExtension == "JPG" || $imageExtension == "jpg")
            {
                $image = rand(0, 100000).rand(0, 100000).rand(0, 100000).time().".".$imageExtension;

                $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, userid, email, password, image) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$userid','$email','$password','$image')";
                if(mysqli_query($con, $insertQuery))
                {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_image,"images/$image"))
                    {
                        $error = "You are successfully registered";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error = "Image is not uploaded";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error = "File must be an image. PNG or JPG";
            }
    }

}?> 

<body>

    <div id="error" style=" <?php  if($error !=""){ ?>  display:block; <?php } ?> "><?php echo $error; ?></div>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="menu">
            <a href="quotin_start.php">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
        </div>

        <div id="formDiv">
            <form method="POST" action="signup.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label>First Name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="inputFields" required/><br/><br/>

            <label>Last Name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="lname"  class="inputFields" required/><br/><br/>

            <label>Username:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="userid"  class="inputFields" required/><br/><br/>

            <label>Email:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="email"  class="inputFields" required/><br/><br/>

            <label>Password:</label><br/>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="inputFields"  required/><br/><br/>

            <label>Re-enter Password:</label><br/>
            <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm"  class="inputFields" required/><br/><br/>

            <label>Image:</label><br/>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="imageupload"/><br/><br/>


            <input type="checkbox" name="conditions" />
            <label>I am agree with terms and conditions</label><br/><br/>

            <input type="submit"  class="theButtons"  name="submit" />



            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

**connect.php** I started to use `session_start()` here.

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","****","database");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error occured while connecting with database ".mysqli_connect_errno();
}?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php 
    function email_exists($email, $con)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}


function logged_in()

{
        if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['email']))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}?>
```

I'm also not sure why when I sign up, it doesn't register to my database. It did before I started to try and display username, but anymore. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: According to the link [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), HTTP headers are case-sensitive. Have you tried changing "location" to "Location" in each header() call?

Comment: @ctwheels yes but that's only supposed to run if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: @ADyson you are right, an overlook on my part, I will edit my comment to only include SQL injection remark

Comment: You should look into using stored procedures as well to protect yourself from SQL injection

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in login.php

```
    $_SESSION['userid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userid']);
```

You are trying to store the userid in session but there is no POST variable set for it because you are submitting a login page containing only email & password.
And after successful query execution for login you are again storing an email and not the userid in session.

So after successful password comparison first store the userid in the session by retrieving it from db so that session gets a value which you are expecting on profile page.

So try doing:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'"); //Changed the query
        $retrievepassword = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if(!password_verify($password, $retrievepassword['password']))
        {
            $error = "Password is incorrect";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $retrievepassword['userid'];//storing the retrieved userid from db

            if($checkBox == "on")
            {
                setcookie("email",$email, time()+3600);
            }

            header("location: quotin.php");
        }
```

Comment: Connect.php I have session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['userid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userid']);
 } But I see the username display when only when I sign up. When I log back in, it's gone. Also, I did what you said, but no luck.

Comment: Don't store the session variables like that in connect.php, because there is no post variable set while calling profile.php so session is getting a empty value.

Comment: So I just put all that information, including session_start(), in profile.php?

Comment: No. session_start() has to be there as it is. But once if you store a value in session then no need to do the same on all pages. example here you are making an user to login & storing userid in it, now you can directly use it as $_SESSION['userid'] anywhere in the application if the user is logged in. Also please read about how session works.

Comment: I will do. One more question, sorry. Where would I put all the $_SESSION information. I'm thinking under session_start()? Because I was told that's how you would do it.

Comment: The standard for session initiation will always on top of the php file and it will be great if you can make it in a separate file where u make the connection n other configurations like root path, url etc. n use that file by including it in everypage on top. Next $_SESSION, you can use it wherever necessory ex for login, initiate values after login query n make use of those variables where ever necessory.

Comment: Alright, so if I put $_SESSIONs under  if(isset($_POST['submit'])), will I be able to still see the username that was echo?

Comment: Actually when I log out, and log back in it's gone. I guess it's because of session_destroy?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, when you destroy the session nothing remains in it.

Comment: So what's the proper way to log out and still be able  keep my sessions?

Comment: If you want to logout & want to keep some data then use unset function $_SESSION['userid']. ie. unset($_SESSION['userid']); Now your other session variables will not die.

Comment: session_unset(unset($_SESSION['userid']); or unset($_SESSION['userid']);?

Comment: Only unset & if you feel that the answer is helpful then accept it.